# Why do I need the interface(decorated with [ServiceContract])?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a Service.svc class. In it I have:

```
public class CommentsWCFService : Objects.ISessionIDCommentWCFContract
    {
        public List<Comment> GetComments(string SessionId)
        {
            //dummy data first
            List<Comment> dummyData = new List<Comment>();

            if (SessionId == "123")
            {
                dummyData.Add(new Comment("Comment 1", DateTime.Now));
                dummyData.Add(new Comment("Comment 2", DateTime.Now));
                dummyData.Add(new Comment("Comment 3", DateTime.Now));
            }

            return dummyData;
        }
    }
```

I have implemented the interface because I was told to do so. What im wondering is why I need to inherit an interface that is decorated with the `[ServiceContract]` attribute?

Would .net know? Could I still call the service if I removed this interface all together?

Comment: It depends on how your service is being called. Google "WCF Shared Interface", here's a few [links](http://blogs.crankygoblin.com/blogs/geoff.appleby/archive/2006/06/08/Sharing-Interfaces-in-WCF.aspx) [another one](http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2006/05/17/Share-your-interfaces-_2D00_-avoid-static-proxies_2E00_.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This attribute tells WCF that the interface defines a contract and should be exposed.
See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.aspx) or an arbitrary tutorial about WCF.

Comment: Hi Yeah I looked at that article really helpfull. I now understand that to implement a WCF service that .net demands that you confugure...Address,Contract and Binding Type....Cheers.